# What is the name of a column used to join together rows from different tables?

Tags: database, terminology

I have a table like this:

```
name,height
Alice,1.75
Bob,1.74
```

and then I have a table like this:

```
name,DOB
Bob,1965-04-04
Alice,1972-09-27
```

And I would like to get a table like this:

```
name,DOB,height
Alice,1972-09-27,1.75
Bob,1965-04-04,1.74
```

In database terminology, what is the name of the `name` column? Is that a *primary key*?

Comment: I believe you are referring to relational databases. Question is : has the name column explicitly been defined as a primary key? If not, it cannot be called a primary key in the true sense. If it has been defined as a primary key in the first table, then yes it is a primary key. Also, with respect to the second table, it is the foreign key.

Comment: @CKing I'd say in the example lined out, it is a foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if they have a standard name; I've always referred to them as "the join columns" as a contraction of "the columns participating in the join" or, if talking about the boolean operations they comprise, "join conditions" / "join predicates"

A primary key is a different thing. It is a column or set of columns that guaranteeably uniquely identifies a row in a table. A table doesn't have to have a PK, doesn't have to have one to participate in joins, and joins don't have to use a ny column that is part of a primary key. A table has to have a PK in order to serve as the target of a foreign key; a mechanism that ensures data in one table has related data in another data

In your example, you would probably have all this data in the SAME table. Do not split data across tables needlessly, especially if the relationship between the tables is 1:1

Because a person's birthday never changes, but their height does, it would make more sense to have the table with the birthdays be the primary table, and the table with the heights also have a data column indicating when the height was taken. This table would then be foreign keyed to the main table

```
Person
Name, DOB
Alice, 2000-01-01
Bob, 2001-01-01

Measurement
Name, Height, ReadingDate
Alice, 100, 2002-01-01
Alice, 110, 2003-01-01
Bob, 101, 2002-01-01
Bob, 112, 2003-02-01
Bob, 118, 2004-01-01
```

Measurement.Name cannot be a PK because it is not unique, but we could say that Name+ReadingDate could be (if we had a rule "no two readings on the same day"). This use of two columns as PK wouldn't prevent Meansurement.Name being a foreign key that references Person.Name (which IS a primary key)

Note; I'm not saying that the relationship must be this way round; you could certainly make the DOB table a foreign key to the heights table- it's just that it doesn't really make sense that way round but it makes more sense this way. This structure can answer questions like "how tall was Bob on date X", "what is the average growth rate per month of boys vs girls" or "based on extrapolation how tall might Alice be now?"